# Delphi : Show a TTimer

Tags: delphi, ttimer

Is it possible to show the countdown of a TTimer in a Label ? Like instantly putting the variable in the Label Caption. I was thinking about how I could do, I'm trying to do a visible countdown in the Form.

Comment: A `TTimer` doesn't have a *countdown*. It has an interval, which is managed by Windows. (When the interval passes, Windows sends a `WM_TIMER` message.) If you want to implement a countdown, you'll have to track it yourself; use a small interval for the timer, decrement your counter when you receive the message, and update the label as needed. When your countdown expires, either disable the timer or reset the countdown and start over.

Comment: Yes it is possible to show a countdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ken White said, a `TTimer` doesn't have a 'countdown'. However, of course it is possible to implement a 'countdown' in your application. The following is an example of one way of doing this.

1. Create a new VCL application.
2. Add a private integer variable named `FCount` to your form class.
3. Use the following code as your form's `OnCreate` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCount := 10;
  Randomize;
end;
```

4. Use the following code as your `OnPaint` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  S: string;
begin

  Canvas.Brush.Color := RGB(Random(127), Random(127), Random(127));
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  R := ClientRect;
  S := IntToStr(FCount);
  Canvas.Font.Height := ClientHeight div 2;
  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Segoe UI';
  Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfCenter, tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter]);

end;
```

5. Add a `TTimer` to your form, and use the following code as its `OnTimer` handler:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FCount = 0 then
  begin
    Timer1.Enabled := false;
    MessageBox(Handle, 'Countdown complete.', 'Countdown', MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    Close;
  end
  else
  begin
    Invalidate;
    dec(FCount);
  end;
end;
```

8. Call the `Invalidate` method in the form's `OnResize` handler.
9. Run the application.

Answer (score 1):

Let's grab the `FCount` variable and keep the things simple.

Here the timer stops itself when the count reaches `0`.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCount := 10;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.Caption := IntToStr(FCount);
  Dec(FCount);
  if FCount < 0 then begin
    FCount := 10;
    Timer2.Enabled := False;
  end;
end;
```

---

The following uses an approach based on the `TThread` class which avoids to grab the `FCount` variable from the [Andreas Rejbrand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947776/delphi-show-a-ttimer/33948019#33948019)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
      var
        countFrom, countTo: Integer;
        evt: TEvent;
      begin
        countFrom := 10;
        countTo := 0;
        evt := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
        try
          while countTo <= countFrom do begin
            TThread.Synchronize(procedure
                begin
                  label1.Caption := IntToStr(countFrom);
                end);
            evt.WaitFor(1000);
            Dec(countFrom);
          end;
        finally
          evt.Free;
        end;
      end).Start;
end;
```

Comment: In the thread solution, there is a need to synch with the VCL thread when updating the label.

Comment: @ChristianHolmJørgensen Thank you, I forgot about that. You're absolutely right